# Login.php redirects to homepage instead of the header location

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication

I am trying to make a notice board where only the admin can login and post updates(for a school) and I am very new to php. My code works fine in MAMP server on mac, but when I upload it to the 000webhost.com for testing purposes, it does not redirect to the correct page after login and redirects to the index.php page.

Here is my code. I did session_start in my conf.php file.

```
<?php

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true) {
   header('location: logout.php');
   exit;
}

//check if not authorized

// Include config file
require_once '../conf.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$email = $password =  '';
$email_err = $password_err =  '';

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

   // Check if email is empty
   if (empty(trim($_POST['email']))) {
      $email_err = 'Please enter email.';
   } else {
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
   }

   // Check if password is empty
   if (empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
      $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
   } else {
      $password = trim($_POST['password']);
   }

   // Validate credentials
   if (empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)) {
      // Prepare a select statement
      $sql = 'SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ?';


      if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
         // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $param_email);

         // Set parameters
         $param_email = $email;

         // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
         if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if email exists, if yes then verify password
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
               // Bind result variables
               mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $email, $hashed_password);
               if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                  //if ( password_verify( $password, $hashed_password ) ) {
                  if (($password == $hashed_password)) {
                     // Password is correct, so start a new session
                     //session_start();

                     // Store data in session variables
                     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                     $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

                     // Redirect user to welcome page
                     header('Location: add_notice.php');
                  } else {
                     // Display an error message if password is not valid
                     $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                  }
               }
            } else {
               // Display an error message if email doesn't exist
               $email_err = 'No account found with that email.';
            }
         } else {
            echo 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
         }

         // Close statement
         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      }
   }

   // Close connection
   mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Please help me with it. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: is ```logout.php``` your welcome screen?

Comment: please add also the form

Comment: Move require_once '../conf.php'; right to the top.

Comment: @fraggley moving it to the top worked for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @MaxMuster I knew the form was working fine so I did not add it

Comment: @WanPeninsula no I am doing logout just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close off the question...

If you are calling `session_start()` in the conf.php file then it needs to be included before any call for `$_SESSION[]` variables.

Right now you are checking for `$_SESSION['loggedin']` before initialising the `$_SESSION` variables with `session_start()`.

Move require_once '../conf.php'; above that if statement and it will work e.g.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once '../conf.php';

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true) {
   header('location: logout.php');
   exit;
}

//check if not authorized

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$email = $password =  '';
$email_err = $password_err =  '';

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

   // Check if email is empty
   if (empty(trim($_POST['email']))) {
      $email_err = 'Please enter email.';
   } else {
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
   }

   // Check if password is empty
   if (empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {
      $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
   } else {
      $password = trim($_POST['password']);
   }

   // Validate credentials
   if (empty($email_err) && empty($password_err)) {
      // Prepare a select statement
      $sql = 'SELECT id, email, password FROM users WHERE email = ?';


      if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
         // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $param_email);

         // Set parameters
         $param_email = $email;

         // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
         if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Check if email exists, if yes then verify password
            if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
               // Bind result variables
               mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $email, $hashed_password);
               if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
                  //if ( password_verify( $password, $hashed_password ) ) {
                  if (($password == $hashed_password)) {
                     // Password is correct, so start a new session
                     //session_start();

                     // Store data in session variables
                     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                     $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

                     // Redirect user to welcome page
                     header('Location: add_notice.php');
                  } else {
                     // Display an error message if password is not valid
                     $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                  }
               }
            } else {
               // Display an error message if email doesn't exist
               $email_err = 'No account found with that email.';
            }
         } else {
            echo 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.';
         }

         // Close statement
         mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      }
   }

   // Close connection
   mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: Accepted your answer. Also, it makes sense too. Thank you so much for the help.